# Elegant way to solve this extreme value problem

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, optimization

I want to show that $$ \sup_{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \lbrace (0,0) \rbrace} \frac{(ax+by)^2}{x^2+y^2} =a^2+b^2 $$ where $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ are fixed (this problem appears when one tries to estimate the operator norm of functionals from $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ which all have the form $(x,y) \mapsto ax+by$).

**One way to do this** is to compute the partial derivatives (which I did) to see that they both vanish at $y=\frac{b}{a}x$ and $y=-\frac{a}{b}x$. Plugging these value into the function, one indeed obtains $a^2+b^2$.

The downside of this approach is that one would also have to show that the function is concave and tends to $-\infty$ for $x,y \to -\infty$ in order to see that these are actually maxima.

**Another way** would presumably be  to plugin in $x=1$ and $y=\frac{b}{a}$  to see that "$\geq$" holds and to somehow estimate $"\leq$"

Can someone help me with one of the approaches above or -even better- point me to a more elegant way of doing this?

Comment: The Cauchy-Schwarz inequality is quick there.

Comment: @DanielFischer Ahhhhh... thanks so much! In hindsight that was a very stupid question. If you want the reputation you can post this as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: I've posted an answer, but that doesn't mean I'd object if you prefer to delete the question. Just, if you don't, it can get out of the unanswered queue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The quickest way is to note that

$$\sup_{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\setminus \{(0,0)\}} \frac{(ax+by)^2}{x^2+y^2} = a^2 + b^2$$

is just the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality for the standard inner product on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Without using that, one can observe that $f(x,y) = \frac{(ax+by)^2}{x^2+y^2}$ is homogeneous of degree $0$, i.e. $f(tx,ty) = f(x,y)$ for all $t > 0$. Thus one wants to find the maximum of $f$ on the unit circle $\{(x,y) : x^2+y^2 = 1\}$, and can use e.g. the method of Lagrange multipliers or a parametrisation $(\cos\varphi,\sin\varphi)$ of the unit circle to find the maximum. For the Lagrange multipliers, we get

$$(ax+by)\cdot (a,b) = \lambda\cdot (x,y),$$

so the extrema are at the points where $ax+by = 0$ - these are minima - and where $(x,y)$ is a multiple of $(a,b)$ (unless $a = b = 0$, in which case $f \equiv 0$ is obvious anyway), which are maxima.